# Access onprem SAML / OAuth protected SAP API with Azure AD authentication (ADFS federated)

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, saml, adfs, sap-gateway

Context:

- AD domain, AAD Connect, Office365 tenant
- ADFS deployed, federation between AD and AAD
- SAP GW on premise, with SAML and OAuth configured
- SAP GW does not support integration with AAD (only SAML SSO, and it's required to use it's own OAuth server)

Scope:

I'm trying to build an application in SharePoint online where the authenticated user can:

- fetch data from the SAP gateway (oh behalf of the user)
- fetch data from Microsoft Graph

Design (So far):

- The user access Office 365 and authenticate with ADFS
- With ADAL/MSAL I'm able to acquire an OAUTH token from AAD and get data from Graph (supported by the registration of an Enterprise application in AAD with permission for Graph)

Issue:

- The OAuth token generated by AAD is not validated by SAP OAuth Server onprem if I try to access the onprem SAP API.

What should I do?

- Should I get another SAML assertion directly from ADFS to get another OAuth token for SAP OAuth Server to access the onpremise SAP API? If so, how can I get a SAML assertion (to call the SAP OAuth server) from ADFS without passing to adfs user credential (like in this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion) and by using information available in the user session (already authenticated with AAD)?
- Is there a way to configure ADFS to accept SAML assertions / JWT tokens originating from AAD?
- Should I do something else?

Any idea on how could I support this scenario?

Thank you

Comment: There are multiple guides [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/20/your-s4hana-environment-part-7-fiori-launchpad-saml-single-sing-on-with-azure-ad/), [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sap-netweaver-tutorial) and [more generic here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications). Check these and come back with more concrete question - like what exactly are you doing and what does not work, what errors you see, etc. The fact that you have federated Azure AD to ADFS is less relevant.